# Keyboard-activated function

Tags: javascript, button, alt

On a website of my clients there is a function in Javascript that pressing alt + 5 activates this function:

```
var chgpgPage = {
    goToPrincipal:function(){
        window.location.href = 'www.mysite.org';
    },
}
```

The part of the code that triggers the function is this:

```
: this.AV102pressedSelected.Key == "alt+5"
? chgpgPage.goToPrincipal()
```

I now need the alt + 4 button to trigger another function that would be this:

```
require(["dojo", "dijit/form/Button"], function() {
    
    // Invert Button
    new dijit.form.Button({
        onClick: function() {
            dojo.toggleClass(document.documentElement, 'inverted');
        }
    }, 'invertButton');
    
});
```

How would the trigger code look?

```
: this.AV102pressedSelected.Key == "alt+4"
? ???????????????????
```

How would you go about triggering the above function? Since it doesn't have var like the other one?

Today the invertButton function is triggered by a button:

```
<button id="invertButton">Click to Invert</button>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can add a function in **chgpgPage** like this,

```
var chgpgPage = {
    goToPrincipal:function(){
        window.location.href = 'www.mysite.org';
    },
    invert:function(){
        require(["dojo", "dijit/form/Button"], function() {
            ojo.toggleClass(document.documentElement, 'inverted');
        });
    }
}
```

**invert** function will have the logic to invert. And you will trigger this function as:

```
: this.AV102pressedSelected.Key == "alt+4"
? chgpgPage.invert()
```